# Como remover uma classe de vários elementos, cujos nomes obedeçam determinado critério

Tags: javascript

Preciso remover todas as classes que comecem com `btn-*`.

Meu script:

```
if (document.getElementById('contato_'+id).classList.contains('btn-danger') ){
    document.getElementById('contato_'+id).classList.remove('btn-danger');
    document.getElementById('contato_'+id).classList.add('btn-success');
}
```

O problema é que ele só exclui uma classe específica.

Comment: Você poderia selecionar as classes por expressão regular, trocar o nome de todas elas para um mesmo nome e então remover.

Comment: Queres remover num elemento específico ou em todos?

Comment: No meu caso esse código é parte de uma função da qual pega um elemento em específico. Daí quero remover do mesmo elemento a classe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta você percorrer todas as classes do seu elemento e remover aquelas que satisfazem a sua condição:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')

for (let className of [...button.classList]) {
  console.log(`Testando a classe ${className}`)
  if (className.startsWith('btn-')) {
    button.classList.remove(className)
    console.log(`Removida a classe ${className}`)
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
```

Comment: E se a class começar com outro nome ? O que pode ser feito ?

Comment: @ScrapBench Como assim começar com outro nome?

Comment: `if (className.startsWith('btn-'))` tava a pensar se a class fosse "coisa-pra-chatear btn-primary btn-block" por exemplo, esse If seria validado na mesma ?

Comment: Sim, porque ele considera cada classe separadamente. A condição é aplicada em `coisa-para-chatear` e depois em `btn-primary`; como somente a segunda satisfaz a condição, só ela será removida.

Comment: Muchas gracias 

Comment: Vc é o bichão mesmo hein! :D

Answer (score 2):

Insira em todos os seus `<button>` a class btn em prefixo, exemplo:

```
<button class="btn btn-sucess">
```

Dessa forma o metodo `getElementsByClassName();` vai criar uma array desses buttons;

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");


var len = btns.length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
   if(btns[i].className.includes('btn-')){
      btns[i].className = ''; //vazio se quiser retirar todas as classes;
      btns[i].className = 'nome_de_outra_class';
   }
}
```

> No meu caso esse código é parte de uma função da qual pega um elemento em específico. Daí quero remover do mesmo elemento a classe.

```
function removerClass(elem,class_que_deseja_remover){
  if(elem.className == class_que_deseja_remover){
   // codigo a executar
  }
}
```

Comment: Essa função `document.getElementById('contato_'+id).classList.remove('btn-danger')` já remove classe específica. Gostaria de excluir as classes com prefixo   " `btn-` "

Comment: procura entao com `if(btns[i].className.includes('btn-')){ //fazer algo}` editei a resposta pra incluir isso

Comment: Cuidado que `includes` procura na *string* inteira, o que retornaria `true` para a classe `foobtn-yellow` mesmo sem possuir o prefixo desejado.

Comment: dar um espaço antes do entao resolve isso ? `' btn-'`
eu mei que ja sabia disso dai ter feito nao um querySelector mas elementByClassName pra filtrar antes